# Configure dummy sound device on server with snd-dummy

Tags: sound

### Question:

How to configure a dummy sound device on a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has no sound HW?

I basically just want various apps, `aplay` as a concrete target, to be happy, like they'd be if the system had real sound card. How the solution mixes Alsa, Pulseaudio, OSS, or whatever, that doesn't matter.

### What I have done currently:

At the moment I have just added this one line to `/etc/modules`:

```
snd-dummy
```

and after reboot, `lsmod | grep snd` output is this:

```
snd_dummy              20483  0 
snd_pcm               102099  1 snd_dummy
snd_page_alloc         18710  1 snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69238  7 snd_dummy,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
```

But, it seems I need to do more, because...

### What kind of problem I see:

When I run `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`, I get:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

---

So, how to get this to work? Or how to trouble shoot a sound problem effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. It's simply a matter of permissions!

So, complete steps that worked for me, as root:

- Add `snd-dummy` line to `/etc/modules`
- Edit `/etc/group` and add desired user(s) to `audio:x:29:` line (group ID may be different I suppose)
- Reboot for changes to take effect and verify that they remain in effect.